# Using Riverpod code generator on a class and overriden build() method

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am migrating my current Flutter app to riverpod 2.0. I have a provider that contains a class. I call the asynchronous methods in that class and render UI by watching that provider as you know.

When I use riverpod code generator with the `@riverpod` annotation on the class, it overrides a build method. I returned `null` to the `build()` method and created my provider.

I am using the `ref.watch(provider.notifier).asyncMethod` to call the methods without a problem but I could not figure out what the build method does. It says it initializes an `AsyncNotifier`. When to use this `build()` method.

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: `build` is supposed to return the initial state for your provider